# How to associate a Template (Modern SP-Page) with a custom content type?

Tags: sharepoint-online, content-type, modern-pages, template

I tried to create a custom Content Type based on Site Page, but I cannot associate a certain Modern Page Template to it (Error occurs on creation).

Is there any way to overcome or workaround this?

Comment: it works when I do it. What's the error?

Comment: Hi @DerekGusoff - thanks for the feedback. What you probably did was create a page template based on a certain content type. when you create a content type, and define the template URL. On a Site Page creation you are redirected to the template itself and not a new page based on that template.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The workaround is doing it the other way around. Create first the Content Type (without template defined), assign it to a corresponding site pages library, and then create a template modern-page based on that specific Content Type.